# Program Freezes on MessageBox()

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Here's the problem:  The main GUI thread is performing a SendMessage to another GUI thread (yes, there are multiple GUI threads, and unfortunately this cannot change).  When that second GUI thread receives the SendMessage, it may decide to display a message box.  Some of the time, that MessageBox will 'freeze' the entire application.

More specifically, the message box shows up, but the entire GUI is hung (user input does not work anywhere).

I've verified with a debugger that the second GUI thread is spinning in the DialogBox2() function defined in user32.dll.  I can see in the disassembly that a message pump is being executed (I see IsDialogMessage/TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage being called).  Using spy++, I do not see any messages being processed for the message dialog box window.  I do see messages getting processed on the main GUI window (such as WM_SETCURSOR, though I do not thin they are being processed as I believe SendMessage doesn't execute a message pump).

The second thread is executing code that is part of an MFC extension DLL, if that matters.

I've tried using AfxMessageBox() / CWnd::MessageBox / ::MessageBox(NULL parent window,...).  All exhibit the same problem.

Has anyone seen anything similar before?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: I found the problem in the first sentence of your question, so I'm not sure why I should read any further. You're using multiple GUI threads, you know that it's a bad idea, and you wonder why you're seeing undesirable behaviour? Hmm.

Comment: More to the point, a MessageBox is a blocking call, whether you use one wrapped by MFC or not. That means it prevents messages from being processed, consistent with the behavior that you describe.

Comment: I understand the MessageBox is blocking.  The MessageBox shouldn't be freezing though (e.g., I should be able to click OK to dismiss it).  And as I said, the application cannot change to a single GUI thread.  I agree that it's a bad idea, but I didn't write it.

Comment: I tried invoking MessageBox with a NULL parent, to try and rule out that possibility.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx and Raymond Chen's blog makes for useful reading. For example windows and message queues get associated with the creating thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be that blocking one of the GUI threads causes the problem.

Try this:

Replace the ::SendMesage with ::PostMessage followed by a ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects loop. You will need to pass an event handle that signals when the message box is closed.

It will probably solve the problem.

Just be careful which messages you dispatch in you ::MsgWaitForMultipleObjects loop.